# Mouse stuttery on desktop but not on applications?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, mouse, cursor

I've just installed Ubuntu 20 (from fresh dual-boot) and am having a strange issue where the cursor (controlled by normal wireless usb mouse) is slow and stuttery when on the desktop, but is totally normal when hovering over a window. UI is otherwise responsive when this is happening - seems to just be a mouse / cursor issue.

Changing acceleration profile in Tweaks seems so have no effect.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0` and let us know if there is any improvement. This is only temporary until you reboot so don't worry.

Comment: @darth_epoxy This or something I may have done seems to have resolved the issue, thank you!